# Jquery div click show/hide anothe div

Tags: jquery, click, show-hide

I want to show a div after I click another div, and hide that showed div when click that same div.how can i achieved this?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/18pzdbz5/

HTML

---

```
<div class="fixed_rht_panel">
        <span class="fn_btn">Click</span>
        <div class="cnt_sec">
          <div class="txt_hd_f">Option indeterminate disabled</div>
            <span class="pic_cont_f"><img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSdd4yHVdgx335P3gR3Mg9Jm9q-wSzhmqwhsTvjCQekGeQYRnxDw"  alt=""/></span>
            <p>Reprimique eu, vix tota salutandi cotidieque id. In case nominati mpor aliquip te sea, amet sumo virtute eu sea. </p>
            <span class="sentc">Mauris sit amet sodales ipsum. Susp turpis diam, ru</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

---

```
 $(".fn_btn").click( function(){
          $(".cnt_sec").animate({'margin-right': '0'},500);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/18pzdbz5/1/

i used `toggleClass()` and based on if the div has the class i show/hide it

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".fn_btn").click( function(){
        $('.cnt_sec').toggleClass('showDiv');
        if ($('.cnt_sec').hasClass('showDiv')) {
            $(".cnt_sec").animate({'margin-right': '0'},500);
        }
        else {
            $(".cnt_sec").animate({'margin-right': '-450'},500);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cnt_sec").click( function(){
          $(this).animate({'margin-right': '-450px'},500);
      });
```